# Change the inequality in binary search code

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

shouldn't be

```
if(a[mid] < t)return BS(mid+1,high);
else return BS(low,mid);
```

the same as

```
if(a[mid] > t)return BS(low,mid-1);
else return BS(mid,high);
```

But the second one doesn't work, why?

Edit: I mean by doesn't work, that the code doesn't reach the base case.

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: Are those one-based or zero-based indices?

Comment: Are you saying that it goes into an infinite loop? Why not post the entire function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In calculating mid as (low+high)/2 it uses integer division.

In Bref. By example

Let low = 3 , high = 4 , a[3] >= t

so by calling BS(low,high) 
mid = (3+4)/2 = 3 #Integer_division

Since a[mid] >=t So return BS(mid,high) which is equivalent to BS(low,high) #infinite_loop

The solution use the integer division in your side So the code should be like

```
if(a[mid] >= t)return BS(low,mid);
else return BS(mid+1,high);
```

Think this will solve your issue.